# Aceso remoto a archivos tipo *.jar

Tags: java

¿Alguien sabe si es posible tener alojado un grupo de jars en disco y que los proyectos java accedan a él haciendo como referencia, sin necesidad de incluirlos en el proyecto en sí, y así hacer más liviano?. Me comentaron que era posible agregando en el classpath de la pc, pero sinceramente jamás escuche ni visto algo así.

Comment: Visita http://www.chuidiang.com/java/classpath/classpath.php ahí explican todo acerca de las _classpath_. Para ejecutar una clase java que usa una librería externa, se debe seguir la siguiente sintaxis:

java -classpath $CLASSPATH:/ruta/archivo.jar claseJava

Comment: Perfecto, me fijaré. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible. Por ejemplo, puedes tener la siguiente estructura en tu disco (asumiendo sistemas *-nix):

```
/opt
- /carlos
  - /comun
    + lib1.jar
  - /apps
    + miapp.jar
```

Entonces, tu aplicación la podrías ejecutar desde un terminal con los siguientes pasos:

```
$ cd /opt/carlos/apps
$ java -cp .:/opt/carlos/comun/lib1.jar -jar miapp.jar com.paquete.principal.ClasePrincipal
```

El mismo ejemplo anterior pero para Windows:

```
C:\opt
- \carlos
  - \comun
    + lib1.jar
  - \apps
    + miapp.jar
```

Comando:

```
$ C:
$ cd C:\opt\carlos\apps
$ java -cp .;C:\opt\carlos\comun\lib1.jar -jar miapp.jar com.paquete.principal.ClasePrincipal
```

Comment: Excelente Luiggi Mendoza muchas gracias. Ahora lo pruebo!